# String to binary python

Tags: python, networking, byte

This is probably a dummy question for most of you, but i'm facing this problem;

I'm capturing a mac address on the network with scapy,I convert this mac address to "\x00\x21\x23\x24\x25" this way :

```
...
  b = p.sprintf("%Dot11.addr2%")
  print "Sending to this MAC Address",b
  #Here, the mac address looks like 00:00:00:00:00:00
  dstmac = str('\\x'+b.replace(':','\\x'))
  #Now, the mac address looks like this:
  "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
  sendp(dst=dstmac,blablablabla)
...
```

When this script send the mac on the wire, it send the actual \x (and all followed number)encoded in hex instead of sending 00 00 00 00 00 00.

Usually, you can use it this way and it's fine : "sendp(dst="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00",blablablabla)

I think i'm doing something wrong while doing this string manipulation, or encoding.

Any input on this will help !

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\x` notation is for string literals. Decode the string as hex instead.

```
>>> '123456789abc'.decode('hex')
'\x124Vx\x9a\xbc'
```

Comment: just be sure to remove the colons in the string

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `replace(':','\\x')` you aren't doing what you think you are doing.  You are replacing the `:` with the characters `\x` not converting the numbers to their binary value.
If you did a `print` of `dstmac` you would get `'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'`

you could get the effect you are looking for by doing the following

as specified in another answer to get what you are looking for you should

`dstmac = b.replace(':','').decode('hex')`

which is remove the `:` and decode the string as if it was hex